# Locate or open another page in a new tab aftetr closing the current page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my ASP.NET web form I want an on-close event that when user closes the current page (let's call it `Current.aspx`), and if `Default.aspx` is not already loaded in the same browser application, `Default.aspx` will be opened in a new **tab**; otherwise, the browser will locate `Default.aspx` and present it to the user. I am thinking about something like this (updated):

```
    <%-- in Current.aspx--%>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //if Default.aspx is not loaded
           if (!window.opener.isClosed)
        Window.onunload = function () {
            Window.opener.reload(true);
            // TO DO: go to the tab where Default.aspx is located
        }
    else window.onunload = function () {
        window.opener.open(window.opener, '_blank', 'width=500, height = 500');
    }
```

Can someone help me please

Answer (score 0):

you may need to wrap it in a function

```
window.onunload = function(){ 
    window.open('Default.aspx', '_blank', 'width=500,height=500');
}
```

because otherwise you are assigning the result of the window.open function to the handler, instead of the function to open the new window

as for tracking the existence of Default.aspx? you'll have to coordinate that manually, because the browser will not let you search through the tabs.